Reuse query plan in spark structured streaming
We have a structured streaming job in spark and we have input data coming as micro batches. The dataset inside the micro batches have like 250 columns. I am trying to find if there is a way to reuse the query plan so that the micro batches spend less time in query planning.
I read through the internet and figured we can cache in the query execution rdd and that basically reuses the query plan. I tried implementing the concept and below is the code which i tried
.foreachBatch(
            (VoidFunction2<Dataset<Row>, Long>)
                (ds, batchId) -> {
                  if (!ds.isEmpty()) {
                    val rdd = ds.queryExecution().toRdd().toJavaRDD();
                    rdd.cache();
                    ExpressionEncoder<Row> encoder = RowEncoder.apply(ds.schema());
                    JavaRDD<Row> collection =
                        rdd.mapPartitions(
                            (Iterator<InternalRow> iter) -> {
                              ArrayList<Row> out = new ArrayList<>();
                              while (iter.hasNext()) {
                                Row output = encoder.createDeserializer().apply(iter.next());
                                out.add(output);
                              }
                              return out.iterator();
                            });
                    Dataset<Row> datsetFromRdd =
                        ds.sparkSession().createDataFrame(collection.rdd(), ds.schema());
                    
                    //psuedo code to write to output
                    writer.save(datsetFromRdd);    
                  }
                })


the above code generated the below error
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkUnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression: getcolumnbyordinal(0, StructField(BA,NullType,true), StructField(Id,NullType,true), StructField(SC,StringType,true), ... 12 more fields)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.cannotEvaluateExpressionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:73) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.3.1-amzn-0.1.jar:3.3.1-amzn-0.1]


I also searched more on the internet like this document
text
the code is mostly written in scala and my code above is in java.
I was thinking of writing code below

.foreachBatch(
            (VoidFunction2<Dataset<Row>, Long>)
                (ds, batchId) -> {
                  if (!ds.isEmpty()) {
                    val rdd = ds.queryExecution().toRdd().toJavaRDD();
                    rdd.cache();
                     List<Attribute> seq = new ArrayList<>();
                    ExpressionEncoder<Row> encoder = RowEncoder.apply(ds.schema()).resolveAndBind(JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(seq.iterator()).asScala().toSeq(), ds.sparkSession().sessionState().analyzer());
                    JavaRDD<Row> collection =
                        rdd.mapPartitions(
                            (Iterator<InternalRow> iter) -> {
                              ArrayList<Row> out = new ArrayList<>();
                              while (iter.hasNext()) {
                                Row output = encoder.fromRow(iter.next());
                                out.add(output);
                              }
                              return out.iterator();
                            });
                    Dataset<Row> datsetFromRdd =
                        ds.sparkSession().createDataFrame(collection.rdd(), ds.schema());
                    
                    //psuedo code to write to output
                    writer.save(datsetFromRdd);    
                  }
                })



I am not sure how to use the below snippet lines of code in java
ExpressionEncoder<Row> encoder = RowEncoder.apply(ds.schema()).resolveAndBind();
Row row = encoder.fromRow(internalRow)


Any help on pointers on how to reuse query planning for streaming jobs or help to fix the above lines in java will be useful.

The below code worked for me
val rdd = ds.queryExecution().toRdd().toJavaRDD();
                rdd.cache();
                val attributes =
                    JavaConverters.asJavaCollection(ds.schema().toAttributes()).stream()
                        .map(Attribute::toAttribute)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                val encoder =
                    RowEncoder.apply(ds.schema())
                        .resolveAndBind(
                            JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(attributes.iterator())
                                .asScala()
                                .toSeq(),
                            SimpleAnalyzer$.MODULE$);
                JavaRDD<Row> collection =
                    rdd.mapPartitions(
                        (Iterator<InternalRow> iter) -> {
                          ArrayList<Row> out = new ArrayList<>();
                          while (iter.hasNext()) {
                            Row output = encoder.createDeserializer().apply(iter.next());
                            out.add(output);
                          }
                          return out.iterator();
                        });
                Dataset<Row> datsetFromRdd =
                    ds.sparkSession().createDataFrame(collection.rdd(), ds.schema());
 //psuedo code to write to output
                writer.save(datsetFromRdd);

